# Testing capacity without using a loop

Tags: java, loops, data-structures, junit, junit4

I implemented a data structure that has a capacity limit. If the number of elements inserted is more than the capacity, it throws an exception.

I would like to test that the class does throw the exception without using a loop, as there is always a risk of a buggy loop.

```
 public void addElt(String s)
    {
        if(elements.size() < 20)
        {
            elements.addFirst(s);
            index = 0;
        } else
        {
            throw new BufferOverflowException();
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do it?
thanks

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the data structure code.

Comment: Hard code X + 1 statements that insert elements into your data structure where X is the capacity of your data structure -- or, you can write a loop and make sure it's not buggy.

Answer (score 0):

With a loop, assuming you have an instance of your class called `thing`, that might look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
  thing.addElt(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

without a loop

```
thing.addElt("1");
thing.addElt("2");
thing.addElt("3");
thing.addElt("4");
thing.addElt("5");
thing.addElt("6");
thing.addElt("7");
thing.addElt("8");
thing.addElt("9");
thing.addElt("10");
thing.addElt("11");
thing.addElt("12");
thing.addElt("13");
thing.addElt("14");
thing.addElt("15");
thing.addElt("16");
thing.addElt("17");
thing.addElt("18");
thing.addElt("19");
thing.addElt("20");
thing.addElt("21"); // <-- should throw your Exception
```

Comment: but if the capacity is 1000!

Comment: Then use a loop, like I said at the start. Or hard code 1001 entries.

Comment: @user199 Actually, rather than indulging this question, we should be challenging the notion that a three line loop would be any more buggy than 1000 lines of copy pasta code, each of which would have to be edited by hand. A computer is pretty much designed to handle repetitive calculations for us. Why on earth would you want to avoid using it for its intended purpose? There's something you're not grasping here.